# using sax parse xml file which contents hidden line breaks

Tags: xml, saxparser, remote-server

I'm using sax to parse xml file from remote server, the problem is that xml file has some tags content hidden line break so that i coud not parse it to get data.

```
<description>
ĐB: 09481 1: 72335 2: 23703 3: 02861 - 52441 4: 47646 - 88373 - 55927 - 07223 - 26879 - 60261 - 30624 5: 0484 6: 1980 - 6883 - 6140 7: 0028: 11
</description>
```

Comment: Please post an example program which fails.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what "hidden line break" means in this context. Note however, that SAX does not guarantee to produce the whole content of a data element in one shot (e. g. for big data elements, or data elements crossing a 64 kByte boundary), so some post-processing has to take place in any case to glue together the parts. Here it would be easy, to filter out any unwanted character.